# How to get employee count via joins

Tags: soql, rest

I am trying to write a function that returns a list of companies and how many employees are under that company but am unable to figure out how to do this in a single request.

Given: search term = "foo"

```
Select Name, Id from Account where Name Like "%foo"
```

I get a list of all companies that match my result

```
Select FirstName, LastName from Contact where AccountId = "{company_id}"
```

And I can get all employees from this query

How can I form the SQl so that a single query returns company name and employee count for a given search term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [relationship query](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm).

```
select Id, Name, (Select Id, FirstName, LastName from Contacts) 
from Account 
where Name Like "%foo"
```

Note how the sub query users `from Contacts`. Contacts here is the parent-to-child relationship name from Accounts to Contacts.

If you just just want a count for the number of Contacts on Account just select the ID and then get the size of each Contacts collection.

```
List<Account> fooAccounts = [select Id, Name, (Select Id from Contacts) 
    from Account 
    where Name Like "%foo"];
for(Account a : fooAccounts) {
    Integer contactCount = a.Contacts.size();
    //....
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an Aggregate Query. Note we need to start the query from Contact as sub queries don't support aggregate functions.

```
Select Account.Id, Account.Name, Count(Id) ContactCount 
from Contact 
where Account.Name like '%foo'
Group By Account.Id, Account.Name
```

Comment: This is great! Would you be able to let me how I can get the count of the contacts instead of first and last name